# Connection refused when trying to connect to services in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flannel

I'm trying to create a `Kubernetes` cluster for learning purposes. So, I created 3 virtual machines with `Vagrant` where the master has IP address of `172.17.8.101` and the other two are `172.17.8.102` and `172.17.8.103`.

It's clear that we need `Flannel` so that our containers in different machines can connect to each other without port mapping. And for `Flannel` to work, we need `Etcd`, because flannel uses this `Datastore` to put and get its data.

I installed `Etcd` on master node and put `Flannel` network address on it with command `etcdctl set /coreos.com/network/config '{"Network": "10.33.0.0/16"}'`

To enable `ip masquerading` and also using the private network interface in the virtual machine, I added `--ip-masq --iface=enp0s8` to `FLANNEL_OPTIONS` in `/etc/sysconfig/flannel` file.

In order to make `Docker` use `Flannel` network, I added `--bip=${FLANNEL_SUBNET} --mtu=${FLANNEL_MTU}'` to `OPTIONS` variable in `/etc/sysconfig/docker` file. Note that the values for `FLANNEL_SUBNET` and `FLANNEL_MTU` variables are the ones set by `Flannel` in `/run/flannel/subnet.env` file.

After all these settings, I installed `kubernetes-master` and `kubernetes-client` on the master node and `kubernetes-node` on all the nodes. For the final configurations, I changed `KUBE_SERVICE_ADDRESSES` value in `/etc/kubernetes/apiserver` file to `--service-cluster-ip-range=10.33.0.0/16`
 and `KUBELET_API_SERVER` value in `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet` file to `--api-servers=http://172.17.8.101:8080`.

This is the link to [k8s-tutorial project](https://github.com/yubar45/k8s-tutorial) repository with the complete files.

After all these efforts, all the services start successfully and work fine. It's clear that there are 3 nodes running when I use the command `kubectl get nodes`. I can successfully create a `nginx` pod with command `kubectl run nginx-pod --image=nginx --port=80 --labels="app=nginx"` and create a service with `kubectl expose pod nginx-pod --port=8000 --target-port=80 --name="service-pod"` command.

The command `kubectl describe service service-pod` outputs the following results:

```
Name:           service-pod
Namespace:      default
Labels:         app=nginx
Selector:       app=nginx
Type:           ClusterIP
IP:             10.33.39.222
Port:           <unset> 8000/TCP
Endpoints:      10.33.72.2:80
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

The challenge is that when I try to connect to the created service with `curl 10.33.79.222:8000` I get `curl: (7) Failed connect to 10.33.72.2:8000; Connection refused` but if I try `curl 10.33.72.2:80` I get the default `nginx` page. Also, I can't ping to `10.33.79.222` and all the packets get lost.

Some suggested to stop and disable `Firewalld`, but it wasn't running at all on the nodes. As `Docker` changed `FORWARD` chain policy to `DROP` in `Iptables` after version 1.13 I changed it back to `ACCEPT` but it didn't help either. I eventually tried to change the `CIDR` and use different IP/subnets but no luck.

Does anybody know where am I going wrong or how to figure out what's the problem that I can't connect to the created service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can see that you have that is conflicting is the PodCidr with Cidr that you are using for the services.

The Flannel network: `'{"Network": "10.33.0.0/16"}'`. Then on the kube-apiserver `--service-cluster-ip-range=10.33.0.0/16`. That's the same range and it should be different so you have your kube-proxy setting up services for `10.33.0.0/16` and then you have your overlay thinking it needs to route to the pods running on `10.33.0.0/16`.  I would start by choosing a completely non-overlapping Cidrs for both your pods and services.

For example on my cluster (I'm using Calico) I have a podCidr of `192.168.0.0/16` and I have a service Cidr of `10.96.0.0/12`

Note: you wouldn't be able to ping `10.33.79.222` since ICMP is not allowed in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Rico you were right. after changing `--service-cluster-ip-range` to `10.34.0.0/16` problem solved and now i can send request from all the nodes in cluster to the created service. But i can't understand how the requests can be routed to the service if the ip of the services are not in `Flannel` network. cause i thought it's `Flannel Overlay Network` that makes this connection possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your service is of type ClusterIP which means it can only be accessed by other Kubernetes pods. To achieve what you are trying to do consider switching to a service of type NodePort. You can then connect to it using the command `curl <Kubernetes-IP-address>:<exposedServicePort>`

See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/ for an example of using NodePort.

Comment: I believe he's connecting from the master because he can connect to: `10.33.72.2:80`